# How come I cant grab a specific discord image from chat using playwright browser based web scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord, playwright

Below is my playwright code, I cannot for the life of me understand why it no longer works and have tried using different locators and clicks. when I run the code, I can see it locates the image I want but it cannot click on the image in order to bring up the popup and "open in browser" button, which is necessary for a high quality screenshot, instead it just stays on the image, waiting for the popup, until it throws a timeout exceeded. I cant even take a screenshot of the image in discord chat, it just bugs out and returns a random screenshot of somewhere in the chat, could I be using the wrong locator?

```
def image_grab(playwright: Playwright, prompt) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://discord.com/channels/@me")
    page.get_by_label("Email or Phone Number*").fill(email)
    page.get_by_label("Password*").click()
    page.get_by_label("Password*").fill(password)
    page.get_by_label("Password*").press("Enter")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Midjourney Bot (direct message)").click()
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Message @Midjourney Bot").locator("div").click()
    # logged in
    page.get_by_role("article").filter(has_text=prompt).filter(has_text="#1").click()
    with page.expect_popup() as page1_info:
        page.get_by_role("button", name="Open in Browser").click()
    page1 = page1_info.value
    time.sleep(3)
    page1.get_by_role("img").screenshot(path=str("image1.png"))
    page1.close()
```

I tried changing the locator but I cant find a way to locate the image besides the article role and text filter, I tried changing how I click the image, like double clicking and giving a buffer between mouse up and mouse down, I tried just screenshotting it in chat without bring the image up in a new window which would significantly ruin the quality, but even that didn't work, only returning a screenshot of chat loading animation, when I would turn animations off it would return an image of the page not the element I want.